# Cup of Tea - Luxury Item?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, everyday-life, water, estimation

Some bloke was saying it costs about UK£1.80 to boil water in a kettle (for 4 people) to make a cup of tea. With all the energy crazyness going on at the moment, that is only going to get higher.

Is this true? Is a cup of tea a luxury item?

How much does it cost in energy to boil enough water in a kettle for 4 people? That is about 1.5 litres of water.

We have a electric hob with the electromagnetic thing. You need steel pans to heat them up. Would that be cheaper to boil water?

What is the cheapest way to boil water for tea?

Comment: This may be a start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_heat_capacity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To estimate that,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_heat_capacity tells you that the heat capacity of water is $4.184 \mathrm{~kJ}/(\mathrm{kg}\, \mathrm{K})$. Hence, to heat $1.5\mathrm{~l}$ of water from $10^\circ\mathrm{C}$ to $100^\circ\mathrm{C}$, you'll need
$$1.5\mathrm{~l} \cdot 1\; \frac{\mathrm{kg}}{\mathrm{l}} \cdot 90\mathrm{~K} \cdot 4.184 \frac{\mathrm{kJ}}{\mathrm{kg}\,\mathrm{K}}=564.8\mathrm{~kJ}\,.$$

To compare, $1\mathrm{~kWh}=1000\mathrm{~Wh}=1000\mathrm{~J}/\mathrm{s}\cdot 3600\mathrm{~s}=3600\mathrm{~kJ}$, so boiling your water needs (at least) $0.16\mathrm{~kWh}$.

As a cross-check: To qualify for the "Blauer Engel" ecolabel (see Blauer Engel Document [1](https://produktinfo.blauer-engel.de/uploads/criteriafile/en/DE-UZ%20133-201309-en%20Criteria-2020-01-07.pdf)), boiling one litre from $20^\circ\mathrm{C}$ may take at most $0.115\mathrm{~kWh}$, corresponding (using a similar computation as above) to an efficiency of about $80\%$. Since there are kettles with this ecolabel, this efficiency seems to be technically feasible and state of the art.

So assuming $80\%$, your kettle will
consume $0.16\mathrm{~kWh}/80\mathrm{\% } =0.2\mathrm{~kWh}$ of electric energy. At a cost of $.30 \mathrm{~\$}/\mathrm{kWh}$, this would mean six cents. Of course, you have to adjust for your specific price of electricity.

Note that kettles are generally considered more efficient than hobs "with the electromagnetic thing", so that will most likely come out more expensive.

Gas stoves are certainly less efficient (you mostly heat the air), with  numbers qouted around $30\%$, so you'll need about $0.5\mathrm{~kWh}$ of gas energy. On the other hand, gas is cheaper (per kWh) -- see https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php?title=Natural_gas_price_statistics. This tells us that in 2021, most European contries had gas prices below $0.1~\mathrm{€/kWh}$, which would lead to five €-cents, so roughly the same amount.

So, the price is not in the fractions of cents, but tea is not yet a luxury item.

Comment: Good answer, though you've mixed up Watts (power) and Joules (energy) in explaining what a $\mathrm{~kWh}$ is. Specifically $1\mathrm{~kWh}=1000\mathrm{~Wh}=1000\mathrm{~J}/\mathrm{s}\cdot 3600\mathrm{~s}=3600\mathrm{~kJ}$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the 80% efficiency. Where does the remaining 20% go, if it's not turned into heat?

Comment: @Vorbis Most likely it goes into heat that does not end up in the water, i.e. heating the kettle itself and the kitchen air.

Comment: @FTT thanks, fixed

Comment: Thanks, your calculations and Rob's pricing below. We appear to be 3 times as much in my county in the UK before the increase next month. So that would put the cost for us to be about $0.18. Which is starting to suggest the bloke referred to in the OP was a decimal point out.

Comment: @Rewind Yes, UK£1.80 seems to be (at least) a factor of ten off.

Answer (score 2):

My electricity costs roughly USD \$0.10 per kilowatt-hour. My electric stove has big burners at 2500 watts and small burners at one kilowatt.  Making tea on the small burner requires substantially less than one hour, and therefore costs substantially less than ten cents.

A dedicated electric kettle is more energy-efficient than the stove, and costs even less.

Comment: Wow, locally our cost is $0.30 per kilowatt-hour and the prices are just about to go up further next month by a massive amount. Even so, it sounds like the bloke the OP question is refering to has got a decimal place in the wrong place.

Comment: Possible explanation: a dumb web search for "energy to boil water" might give you the energy required to turn water into vapor, which is about five times more than the energy required to raise liquid water's temperature from 0 ºC to 100 ºC. But even at your electricity rates, I don't think it would take six hours to boil the kettle dry on the small burner. The number you heard is just wrong.